# Knockout foreach with ASP.NET MVC Razor Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a Razor Helper that renders some markup. The Razor Helper renders a div that needs to have an ID that is equal to the ID of its accompanying ViewModel.

My issue is that this helper method needs to be called from within a Knockout foreach loop. For each item in the collection, I need to render the Razor Helper mentioned above. How can I possibly do this (and pass in a ViewModel with right ID) for each item in the collection? Are my only options to use Ajax or an iframe or something?

Comment: Maybe add a little code. This question is rather complex to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Razor helper, because your knockout code (client side) will be executed after your View will be rendered (server side). Certainly, you can add some inline calls to razor helper in script block and it will work as expected, but knockout's template engine will be executed on client side when browser document will be ready.
So, in your case - only ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Razor to help render a [Knockout Template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) that would be bound to each item in your knockout collection.

You may get your div id to bind using Knockout's [attr](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding

I haven't tried this, but I don't see why it could not work.